How to query variants for structured products (commerce 5.2) to sort products
With Commerce 5.2 it is possible to change product type to structures, which was done in order to manually sort products (https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/discussions/2302).
I changed my product types to structures inside the panel.
In my twig template I have:
// grab current category to filter products
{% set currentCategory = (activeNode and activeNode.getTypeLabel() == 'Categoria') ? activeNode.element : null %}
{% set relatedProducts = craft.products().relatedTo(currentCategory) %}

{% set allVariants = craft.variants.hasProduct(relatedProducts) %}

{% set results = allVariants
        // limit, search, relatedTo and with not relevant stuff
    .orderBy('featuredProduct DESC, postDate DESC, sortOrder ASC, score')
%}


Note that I do not list products but variants, and I want to sort first by products sorting and then list ordered variants.
But if I change the orderBy params with something like lft (here docs):
.orderBy('featuredProduct DESC, lft, postDate DESC, sortOrder ASC, score')
the query is broken because there is no join between structureelements (which holds the lft field) and variants tables.
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'lft' in 'order clause'

Thanks for any suggestion.

Add missing twig code.

Tweak your code a bit. Instead of using hasProduct, which can jumble up the order, call variants on each product as you loop through:
// grab current category to filter products
{% set currentCategory = (activeNode and activeNode.getTypeLabel() == 'Categoria') ? activeNode.element : null %}

{# loop through each product #}
{% for p in craft.products.type('whateverProductType').relatedTo(currentCategory).all %}

  {% for v in p.variants().sortBy([['featuredProduct','desc'],['postDate','desc']]).collect() %}

   {# do whatever #}
   {{ v.description }}<br>

  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}


Thanks, I'm gonna experiment on your suggestion and keep you posted.

I checked your suggestion and indeed hasProduct is messing up the order, but it's kinda hard to adopt the product loop solution in my case since I need to keep it as a variantQuery rather than a collection of objects. I need to filter, search, limit, add where conditions and add relations data (with) later in the code ... I oversimplified the question maybe. I'll keep investigating and keep you posted, thanks.

Just a thought: do you think that https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/5.x/system/products-variants.html#variant-hasproduct  could be somehow seen as  faulty for sorting purpouses as being targeted to "Narrows the query results to only variants for certain products." but can't keep default sorting? I could open an issue, just in case.

FWIW sorting can get complex quickly. You may want to look at something like SuperSort if the built-in Craft methods can’t do what you’re after.

Thanks, I will dig into it.
